# jQuery get refreshes entire page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a page which contains some comments that I need to add edit capbilities to. I created a
partial view to edit them, and I load the partial view inside the div that contains the actual 
comment using jQuery get.

The problem is that the entire page is somehow refreshed when I do 
the asynchronous get and the page position is reset. If I edit an edit found somewhere below,
when the view is reset, I must scroll down to see the actual comment in edit mode. How can I make the page stand still, not to confuse the users?

This is the function I use to do the GET:

```
function redirectToEditComment(url, container, commentID) {
   $.get(url, { id: commentID }, function (data) {
      container.html(data);        
   });
}
```

This is the link I use to trigger editing:

```
<a href="#" onclick="redirectToEditComment(editCommentURL, $('#@containerId'), @comment.Id)">Edit</a>
```

And this is how I set the id for the comment divs:

```
@foreach (var comment in Model.Comments)
{
   containerId = "commentsContainer_" + i++;
```

P.S: The problem is the page is scrolled back to top when I do the jQuery GET. How can I prevent scrolling?

Comment: paste your html also to get it clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your anchor tag, you have set href="#" which is taking you at the top of the page. Either write `href="javascript:void(0);"` or `href="javascript:;"`.

No need to return false from your javascript method.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer on SO: returning false after the jQuery get

```
<a href="#" onclick="redirectToEditComment(editCommentURL, $('#@containerId'), @comment.Id); return false;">Edit</a>
```